# Step is hang during the read() method

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a job and in one of the steps, the reader needs to handle a list of 6000 +/- objects. This is not a big volume of data and it's not the first time that I am working with this size of a volume.

For some reason, the reader can hang for an hour or even more after each chunk in the read() function. I don’t know what is wrong and have no idea how to debug this step.

```
@Autowired
private ModelMapper modelMapper;
@Value("${chunk.size}") //500
private int chunkSize;
@javax.annotation.Resource
private Environment environment;
private ItemReader<Device> delegate;

public void setDelegate(ItemReader<Device> delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
}

@Override
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    
    List<AccountDeviceDto> outboundList = (List<AccountDeviceDto>) stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().get("outboundThatMightSwappedList");
    List <DeviceDto> accountList  = outboundList .stream().map(dto -> dto.getDevice()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Device>>() {}.getType();
    List<Device> mapList = modelMapper.map(accountList,listType);

    setDelegate(new IteratorItemReader<Device>(mapList));
}

@Override
public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    logger.info("** start afterStep **");

    return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
}

@Override
public Device read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
    return delegate.read();
}

 @Data
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "Device")
 public class Device {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "MacAddress")
  private String macAddress;
  ......
  .....
  ....
  ...
  ..
  @Column(name = "LastModifiedDate")
  private LocalDate lastModifiedDate;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "device")
  private List<AccountDevice> accountDeviceList;
}
```

Any idea how this can be debugged to figure what is the bottleneck.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is to find out which line of the code does it hang at and then troubleshoot from there.

Firstly find out the process ID of your spring-batch app by :

```sh
 jps -v
```

Assuming the process ID is 1234 , then use  `jstack` to print out the stack trace of the java thread for this process. You could then see the related threads are hanging at which lines of the codes :

```sh
 jstack 1234
```

Comment: Thank you Ken, Yes I see all the threads but unfortunately it doesn't say much to me

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be putting the list of items in the execution context in a previous step and then reading them from the execution context with a delegate `IteratorItemReader`.

The execution context is persisted between steps, and what's happening is that your big items list is taking time to be deserialized before even starting to read the first item. I'm pretty sure this is the cause of your issue, but you can debug/time the `beforeStep` method to confirm that.

Comment: That's correct, I am moving this list of items between the Steps. I did debug the beforeStep method and it was reasonably fast. The process is getting "choke" during the read method between the chunks. So basically if I defined chunk == 500 then after each 500 the process is hanging for a while.